# Widget on Graph - R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm relatively new to SO and R Shiny - wondering if it's possible to place a widget on top of a graph (say above the legend) such as a ggplot, instead of above, or below, or to the side?

Let me know if anyone knows of any solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via CSS. Please check `htmltools::tagAppendAttributes`:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagAppendAttributes(
    selectizeInput(
      "species",
      "Species",
      choices = unique(iris$Species),
      selected = unique(iris$Species),
      multiple = TRUE,
      options = list('plugins' = list('remove_button'))
    ),
    style = "position: absolute; top: 4%; right: 12%; z-index: 1;"
  ),
  fluidRow(plotOutput("myplot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    iris[iris$Species %in% input$species, ]
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    scatter <- ggplot(data = filtered_data(), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
    scatter + geom_point(aes(color = Species, shape = Species)) +
      xlab("Sepal Length") +  ylab("Sepal Width") +
      ggtitle("Sepal Length-Width")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Is there a way to make the data and graph title wrap around the widget, as opposed to being overlayed (and subsequently covering some of the data/title)?

Comment: @Sean no, I'm not aware of an approach meeting your requirements. However, you could make the widget draggable. Check [shinyjqui](https://yang-tang.github.io/shinyjqui/).

Comment: That's okay, I found a similar solution (different context, same application) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75380455/20154154