# ggplot2 - wrap data around legend in custom position

Tags: ggplot2, graph, legend

When placing a legend in a custom position (using `legend.position = c(x, y)`) in a ggplot, is it possible to format the legend so that it does not overlay the data, and instead, the datapoints wrap around it?

In this example, would it be possible to, say, have ggplot insert extra space in the plot, so that datapoints are not obscured by the legend (without changing the `legend.position`)?

Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)

data(mtcars)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = hp))+
  geom_point(aes(color = mpg))+
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.position = c(0.5, 0.9))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inelegant solution is to add `plot.title(element_text(margin = margin(a, b, c, d)))` where a, b, c and d are padding values for top, right, bottom, left, respectively, and adjust the c value until there is sufficient space. Let me know if you come up with a better solution!